# Epoll add button not working?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm quite new to meteor and I am having some issues.
I am creating an epoll app and here is the link to it: http://epollhouse.meteor.com/
But, when I press the Add question button nothing happens.

Also, for your reference I have posted my source code up onto github: https://github.com/InfamousGamez/epollhouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in epollclient.js

change this: `Questions = new Meteor.Collections("questions");`

to this: `Questions = new Mongo.Collection("questions");`

Comment: are you testing locally?